# EncodeError: <flask_mail.Message object at 0x7f044bf07410> is not JSON serializable

Tags: flask, celery

My final code is looks like the following:

```
@client_route.route('/client/cat-<dir_code>/subscribe/<string:user_id>', methods=['POST'])
@only_client
@is_active_client
# @cache.cached(timeout=60)
def subscribe_abonent(user_id):

    search_form = Search()
    client_id = Client.query.filter_by(tele=session.get('client_phone') ,name=session.get('client_logged_in'), family=session.get('client_family')).first_or_404()
    master = Abonent.query.filter_by(public_id=user_id, slug_direction=g.get('current_directory')).first_or_404()
    client = Client.query.filter_by(id=client_id.id).first_or_404()

    if session.get('client_is_not_subscriber'):
        session.pop('client_is_not_subscriber')
    session['client_is_subscriber'] = client.name + client.family + str(client.id)

        socketio.emit('show_calendar', namespace='/masterCalendar-{}'.format(master.slug, master.public_id.replace('-','')))

        if master.email is not None:
            if master.subscribers_notifications:
                date_now = datetime.now()
                send_email(master.email, 'You got a new subscriber','client/newsletter/new_subscriber',master=master.name + ' ' + master.family, client=client.name + " " + client.family, sent=date_now)

@celery.task
def send_email(to, subject, template, **kwargs):
    with current_app.app_context():
        msg = Message(current_app.config['UBOOK_MAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX'] + ' ' + subject,
                sender=current_app.config['UBOOK_MAIL_SENDER'], recipients=[to])
        msg.body = render_template(template + '.txt', **kwargs)
        msg.html = render_template(template + '.html', **kwargs)
        mail.send(msg)
```

Now everything is working fine, but celery not recognizing the task, the task runs inside the terminal just like your are sending email using `Thread` !!!

**new_subscriber.txt**:

```
Dear Vladimir, Here was {{master}}

You got a new subscriber:

Клиент: Sasha , Here was {{client}}

Получено: 2017-11-23 12:47:23 , Here was {{sent}}
```

Another thing that i forgot to mention that , if i removed the master, client and sent arguments and used `delay()` the code get freezed !!

Comment: What error does implementing that solution throw? Write in here the modified code implementing that solution.

Comment: @LuisOrduz, thanks for your interest dude. I've updated the question take a look !

Comment: What error does it throw when using that second method?

Comment: Post how your `send_email` function looks like now

Comment: I have updated the question again take a look :)

Comment: Not sure exactly what master is, seems like the results of a db query, those are not json serializable either. You don't seem to be using it in send_email anyway so try not passing master. Same with `client`.

Comment: I really can't remove them i need them so the master can know who is the subscriber, but the most interesting here is the master object is the same as the client, why it throw out the error on client object but it ignores the master object, thats mean that master is fine , isn't it ??

Comment: But you're not using them in the `send_email` function. In the code you posted, it's not clear why you need to pass them. Check if it works if you don't pass them as arguments to `delay`.

Comment: @LuisOrduz, dude i've updated the question again !

Comment: Post the template too, to see how you're using them.

Comment: @LuisOrduz, i posted it already :)

Comment: It seems like master and client are only needed for their string representation, so you could just pass that to `delay`, something like `str(master)` and `str(client)`.

Comment: @LuisOrduz, i treid, i also used `pdb` debugger using `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` and placed it right above `if master.email is not None:` now if i traced the flow using letter **n** which means **next** when reach to `send_email.delay()` the application not doing anything forward it get stuck !

Comment: The root cause is that you can only pass primitive types to delay. Master and Client are not that, you are only using those in the template, which means you only need text fields. Check what exactly is the properties from client and master you need (that are primitive) and pass only that to delay. The debugger gets stuck there because delay is just calling an asynchronous task that is run by celery, it isn't in the same thread the debbugger is executing.

Comment: @LuisOrduz, dude take a look at this code its the same as i used for the first time : [flasky-with-celery](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flasky-with-celery/blob/master/app/auth/views.py), here is how his task looks like: [task for sending email](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flasky-with-celery/blob/master/app/email.py), by using his code i got the very first erro that says: `<flask_mail.Message object at 0x7f044bf07410> is not JSON serializable`